# MVC Razor C# Variable used for HTML img tag src

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a lot of images I want to display so I'm using a dynamic partial view to reduce unnecessary code. This is my partial view:

```
@{ string[] imgs = { 
    "src='~/Content/images/1.png'", 
    "src='~/Content/images/2.png'", 
    "src='~/Content/images/3.png'" 
};

@foreach (var img in imgs) { *HTML GOES HERE* }
```

HTML inside foreach loop:

```
<div class="thumbnail-border">
    <img id="modalImage" class="thumbnail-lg" @Html.Raw(img) />
</div>
```

The strange thing is that if I switch out "src" for "alt", the alt works. But having a variable for src as the image path does not work. So my question is:
If I wanted to use a foreach loop to go through an array of strings (the image paths) to use for my , how could I do that?

Comment: And just to clarify, the image path does work by the way. I tried it beforehand with just the image path string in the src="" attribute.

Comment: Define "does not work".  What *does* it do?  What is the client-side HTML generated here?  If the client-side code includes the `~` in the path then that certainly won't "work" because that path means nothing to the browser.  You'd need to translate it to a client-usable path first, using something like `Server.MapPath()`.

Comment: <img id="modalImage" class="thumbnail-lg" src="~/Content/images/1.png"/> works properly (displays my image). However using the @Html.Raw(img) just shows the common error image (blank white image with the broken small square in the top left)

Comment: I just figure that using a variable to insert the exact same string of text into the <img> tag *should* work. But it doesn't so I wonder why

Comment: Is that the actual client-side HTML in the browser?  Or the code you're putting in Visual Studio?  Look at what's actually in the browser.  I suspect that the framework is replacing that path.  But isn't replacing it when it's being constructed in the way you're attempting, so you may need to replace it manually.

Comment: Try removing the `"src="` parts from the values and just have the list of strings be only the paths.  Then just do `src="@img"` in the view.  Then the framework may correct the path for you.  I'm thinking that perhaps the use of `Html.Raw()` is explicitly telling the framework *not* to correct the path.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Forget about `@Html.Raw(img)` - you don't need it here. Use path only (without `src` attribute):

```
@{ 
    var imgs = { 
        "~/Content/images/1.png", 
        "~/Content/images/2.png", 
        "~/Content/images/3.png" 
    };
}

@foreach (var img in imgs) 
{ 
    <img src="@Url.Content(img)" alt="tbd" />
}
```

`Url.Content(img)` is used to resolve root path to the image `~/`.

Comment: @MattD glad to help!